# VB.NET Parenting makes control invisible

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, controls

I have created a form.
I have put 2 panels on it, namely "Panel1" and "Panel2".
I put one button in the "Panel2".

Then I put another button to the form, namely "Button2".

A click on "Button2" executes the following code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Me.Panel2.Parent = Me.Panel1
    ' Me.Panel1.Location = New Point(0, 0) this does not work either

End Sub
```

When I click "Button2", "Panel2" simply disappears.
I expected "Panel2" to be placed within "Panel1", but it is not shown there.

Does anybody see what I did wrong?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: `Me.Panel2.Location = New Point(0, 0)`

Comment: No, no. I do not only want to show it there, I would really like to parent it in the other panel.

Comment: Exactly! you are already setting Panel2's parent to Panel1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to set the position of the other pannel:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Me.Panel2.Parent = Me.Panel1
    Me.Panel2.Location = new point(0,0)

End Sub
```

Comment: I do not only want to show it there, I would really like to parent it in the other panel.

Comment: yeh use the code you have above to make it the parent but change the position of the other panel as per my example, cheers

Comment: This is correct, the Location property *has* to be modified to keep the panel inside the display rectangle of the parent so it remains visible.  Shame on the downvoter.

Comment: Yes, okay, but can you please add         Me.Panel2.Location = Me.Panel1.Location to your reply?

Comment: `Me.Panel2.Location = Me.Panel1.Location` is not correct. The location of the child control must be relative to the parent's location. Try to keep the Panel1 not at 0,0 in the form and see what happens